# Information not displayed as I would like it

Tags: android, json, layout

I am reading data from a json file and it will display information like:

```
Time|Subject|Lecturer
Monday
09:15|Nature|AL23
Monday
10:15|Nature|AL33
Tuesday
09:15|Maths|AS12
Tuesday
12:15|English|AC23
```

but I want the information displayed like

```
Time|Subject|Lecturer
Monday
09:15|Nature|AL23
10:15|Nature|AL33
Tuesday
09:15|Maths|AS12
12:15|English|AC23
```

(where the day is only displayed once). 
The closest I have gotten to getting the information displayed the way I would like it is with:

```
View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

    int a = 0;
    //((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);   
    while(x < 41)
    {
        if(x == 8 || x == 16 || x == 24 || x == 32 || x == 40)
        {

                TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
                valueTV.setText(fetch2.get(a));
                valueTV.setId(x);
                valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                a++;

            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV); 

            System.out.println(x);
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.listview, fetch);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            x++;
        }
    }
```

That does list out the 5 days but only after the Time, Subject and Lecturer but before time. I do have

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableLayout>
```

between the time, subject and lecturer  and the listview (for the times, subjects and lecturers) layout. I did try put the tablelayout in the same xml file that listview is calling the layout from but when I run that I get the following in the debug tab and the app doesn't run.

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1651    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1667 
    ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117   
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 935   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 130 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3687    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 867  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 625 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

I'm not sure how to get the information displayed as I would like it (i.e. the day only showing once).

Comment: This code is essentially unreadable by anyone but you. What are the fetch variables referring to? What is the condition met at 8, 16, 24 etc? Btw, you can shorten that conditional to if(x != 0 && x % 8 == 0 && x < 41)

Comment: The code is in a if loop. You should try using other loops.

Comment: The fetch variables are getting Monday, Tuesdayetc and is printing that to the screen everytime X is 8 or an increment of 8 (as there is only 8 classes a day, I did make a mistake and it is meant to start with x == 0). I am not having a problem with the loops. It a problem with passing the textview information to the "info" id in the xml file. If I put the info id in the main xml file then the day will print out properly, but not where I want it (for it to appear where I want it, it needs to be in the same place where times, classes and lecturers are.)